# Using XBEE from my laptop, I want to assign multiple values in the Arduino

Tags: softwareserial, xbee

I'm trying to control motors by Arduino, from my laptop. I'm using MATLAB to send over packets of data, i.e. 'x=100,y=150,z=200' My scheme was to send this packet to Arduino, and have Arduino extract the numerical values from the string, since the positions of the numbers will always be consistent. I found a code from Arduino forum, written by PaulS, but I can't figure out why it wouldn't move into 'if (xbee.available())' portion of the code. The code is attached below:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define SOP '<'
#define EOP '>'

SoftwareSerial XBee(2, 3); // RX, TX
int test = 0;
bool started = false;
bool ended = false;

char inData[20];
byte index;
char inChar;

void setup()
{
   XBee.begin(9600);
   Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
  // Read all serial data available, as fast as possible
  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    if (XBee.available())
    {
      char inChar = XBee.read();
     }
    if(inChar == SOP)
    {
       index = 0;
       inData[index] = '\0';
       Serial.print(inData);
       started = true;
       ended = false;
    }
    else if(inChar == EOP)
    {
       Serial.print(inChar);
       ended = true;
       break;
    }
    else
    {
      if(index < 19)
      {
        inData[index] = inChar;
        Serial.print(inData);
        index++;
        inData[index] = '\0';
      }
    }
  }

  // We are here either because all pending serial
  // data has been read OR because an end of
  // packet marker arrived. Which is it?
  if(started && ended)
  {
    // The end of packet marker arrived. Process the packet
    Serial.println(inData);
    // Reset for the next packet
    started = false;
    ended = false;
    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
  }
}
```

Comment: what are your connection? This script use Serial AND Xbee, how did you connected them?